# Python executable in #! for any virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

How can I write a python file so that it will run correctly in any virtual environment.  If I put a shabang at the top with the path to my virtual environment's python interpreter, I can run that python file from anywhere, and the program finds all its modules.  However, if someone forks my code and builds a virtual environment in a different location, all of that will break.

Comment: It's really not *your* job to provide a working shebang for the end user. That's why, when you install something through distutils or setuptools, any shebang containing the word `python` is replaced with a shebang supplied by the installer. See https://docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `env` command to find python instead using a hard coded path.
The is a common way to fix such problem.

```
NAME
env - run a program in a modified environment
SYNOPSIS
env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
```

So the shabang text should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

And other script languages can be done like this also:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Comment: Thank you.  I guess that will always use the interpreter than can be found by "which python."  And does that only work with python3's Venv module?   So I guess I should not ever "hard code" my interpreter.  Thanks again!